# Different between VSTO 2010 and 2013 projects

Tags: outlook, vsto

Visual studio suggest to create different VSTO project for outlook 2010 and outlook 2013 like a picture. However my Addin for outlook 2010 also works and for 2013. Any body know about different in these approaches?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that Outlook 2010 interops will be used in the project. So, IntelliSense will not show you methods and properties introduced in latest (Outlook 2013) versions.

See [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.